# How to check if an AdMob banner ad has been loaded? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have my AdMob ads all setup and working, but I want to make an animation for them when they first load in. For example, I have a banner ad right below the bottom of the screen, and when it loads I want it to go up. The animation I have right now:

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.banner.frame.origin.y -= 350
    })
```

works just fine, but only shows to the user if the ad loaded fast enough. What can I do to check?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by setting the delegate of the `GADBannerView` to the desired class, for instance the `self` view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // let's assume that you init the banner view somewhere in your code...
    adMobBannerView.delegate = self
}
```

And then implementing [adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!)](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADBannerViewDelegate#/c:objc(pl)GADBannerViewDelegate(im)adViewDidReceiveAd:):

> Tells the delegate that an ad request successfully received an ad. The
>   delegate may want to add the banner view to the view hierarchy if it
>   hasn’t been added yet.

adding to it your animation code, as follows:

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.banner.frame.origin.y -= 350
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I think I'm missing something though - how is adViewDidReceiveAd being called? It's not being called on it's own with GADBannerView inherited or anything, and I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Can you see an ad in the view? well, if you are pretty sure that you have did the integration steps correctly, then you could implement [func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Any!)](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/api/reference/Protocols/GADBannerViewDelegate#/c:objc(pl)GADBannerViewDelegate(im)adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:) and  add `print(error.localizedDescription)` to it, debug it and you will see what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad F's solution works, except that

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!)
```

is now

```
func bannerViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView)
```